# Dealing cards in Java

Tags: java

I'm super new to programming so excuse me if my code is hard to understand. I was assigned to program a game to deal a card to the user and being it is the top card. I already have my card class made. I just need to know if I'm doing this correctly. It says build successful, but doesn't show anything. Please help!

```
package deck;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author useradmin
 */

// Write a description of class Deck here.
public class Deck {

    private Card[] theCards;
    private int deal;

    public Deck() {
        theCards = new Card[52];
        deal = 52;
        this.fill();
        //fill();
    }
    public int deal() {
        return deal;

    }

    public Card getCard() {
        Card a = null;
        a = theCards[deal-1];
        deal--;
        return a;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String deckString = "New deck shuffled\n";

        for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            deckString += theCards[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
        return deckString;
    }
    public void shuffleCards() {
        Random random = new Random();
        Card temp;
        int topCard;
        for(int i = 0; i<30; i++){
            topCard = random.nextInt(deal);
        }
    }
    private void fill() {
        int i, j;
        int index = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <4; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j < 14; j++){
                theCards[index] = new Card(i, j);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here





    }

    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `main()` is empty. Your program will not do anything

Answer (score 2):

The `public static void main(String[] args)` method is the entry point for your program. When you run your program, this is the first method that gets called. Yours is empty, so nothing will happen.

**Solution**

Make a new class and call it `Application`.

Cut the `public static void main(String[] args){}` method from your `Deck` class and paste it into your new `Application` class.

Inside the `main()` you will need to put some code! I suggest creating a `Deck` object and then printing the contents of the deck using your `toString()` method, just so that you can see that everything is working.

Your new class should look like this:

```
public class Application {

    //Main method (Entry point for program)
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deck myDeck = new Deck(); //Create Deck

        System.out.println(myDeck.toString()); //Print contents of Deck
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have removed the `main()` method from your `Deck` class .

Hope that helps you out. :)

Comment: Hi there, I understood what you told me to do. I've added in a Deck class and a Card class. But I'm not sure what contents to print for Deck.